# Does different instances of boost::array with different sizes generates whole new classes?

Tags: c++, boost

If I make some code like this:

```
boost::array<10> a1;
boost::array<20> a2;
boost::array<30> a3;
```

Will the template generate 3 different classes for me and make the size of my code grow?

If it does, is the compiler/linker smart enough to only include the methods definitions of what I'm actually using? For example: if I use the method 'at' of the a1 object, but never user the method 'at' of the a2 object, then the 'at' of the a2 would be totally discarded.

Comment: @Tomalak The question is dead.

Comment: @pmr: I deleted [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019847/will-multiple-stdarray-instances-bloat-my-executable). This one is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the template generate 3 different classes for me

Yes; every instantiation of a template with different template arguments in in effect a different type.

> and make the size of my code grow?

Extremely unlikely, certainly no worse than enabling inlining does.

> If it does, is the compiler/linker smart enough to only include the methods definitions of what I'm actually using?

Yes, unless you explicitly instantiate the type as a whole.

> For example: if I use the method 'at' of the a1 object, but never user the method 'at' of the a2 object, then the 'at' of the a2 would be totally discarded.

If you never use the method `at` of `a2`, and you didn't explicitly instantiate `boost::array<T, 20>` as a whole, then `boost::array<T, 20>::at()` is never instantiated to begin with and there's nothing to discard.

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiate as a whole"?

Comment: @haole : E.g. `namespace boost { template class array<int, 20>; }`.

Comment: "Extremely unlikely, certainly no worse than enabling inlining does." How so? The code has to go somewhere. Presume here that I'm talking about member functions that _are_ used.

Comment: I think that this question will be better answered with a mean to check if this happens or not. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: @Tomalak : `boost::array<>`'s member functions are extremely trivial, and likely to be inlined anyway; so having different instantiations of `boost::array<>` in a program is unlikely to add any noticable size, if any.

Comment: @haole : Not without significant hassle. In any case, Boost doesn't do that in their code (it would cause ODR violations if done in a header), so if you're not doing it explicitly then it's not happening.

Comment: @ildjarn: Got you. +1 from me!

Comment: Note that good implementations may use techniques that reduce code size. E.g. it's not unheard of to derive from a common, private non-template base class. Also, advanced linkers are capable of folding binary-identical functions even if they'd technically have distinct types.